# Use RegEx to find words that end with period symbol

Tags: sql, regex

Using Regular Expression, find sentences that contain period before ending. Sentences end with .jpg I want to find those sentences that has period before .jpg  For example:

- picture-of-united-states-01.jpg
- picture-of-united-states.01.jpg

**In short if any sentence ends with two periods before then return me the value.**

I want my results to be like:

- picture-of-united-states.01.jpg

Please Note: there is no consistency of the length of sentences. What I mean is I have more than 100 images and names are like:

- picture-of-united-states-01.jpg
- picture-united-01.jpg
- pic-un-states.01.jpg

Comment: None of the sentences posted ends in a double period.. Both of these sentences end in a double period..

Comment: I've edited your post so that it doesn't use numbered lists - it's just too confusing having the period after the number in the list header looking like it's part of the data

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I'd bother with a regex for this..

```
SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE filename LIKE '%.%.%'
```

Will find all rows with at least two periods in the name

```
SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE filename LIKE '%.%.___'
```

Will find all rows with at least two periods in the name, and have 3 letters (like a file extension) after the last period

```
SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE filename LIKE '%..'
```

Will find all rows where the name ends with two periods

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression:

```
".*\..*.jpg"
```

The (.*) looks for any sequence of characters.
(\.) Means followed by one period.
Followed by (.*), any sequence of characters.
Followed by .jpg